# How To Set Cookie in php for userlogin page further I don't how to access

Tags: php, cookies

How To Set Cookie in php for userlogin page further I don't how to access. and more I want more clear explantation about cookie for instance if i access the data in session I could be  accessed in any page with in that website.Here in cookie I don't what to do further. because if i read theory i can understand.But In real time project I don't know what to do next.kindly I request every to explain those topic to me I hope you understand my question.

My coding part:

```
<form name="f1" action="" method="post"/>
username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
setcookie("TestCookie", $_POST['username'],20);
}
?>
This is in view page:
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['TestCookie']))
{
echo $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
setcookie("TestCookie",$_POST['username'],time()+3600);
```

Here, `time()+3600` will expire your cookie in 1 hour.

Comment: sure sir I test this but may I know any time delay can available to check this 30s or 20s , if so where to implement that code

Comment: can any one give me little bit of information about this.

Comment: I have implemented the code, I got in view php.I need further information from your side, what I have to do next, I understood this will expires in 1hour

Comment: Now, you can get value from cookie by using $_COOKIE() function at any page for further requirements.

Comment: thank you using $_COOKIE in will  retrieve data,like how we access for session,but in google search i found store data in client side browser  what does it mean. using setcookie fun we set cookie and using $_cookie we retrieve data , i want to know when the data is stored in browser

Comment: when you set data using setcookie() method, the values are stored on your browser. If you clear your browser cache, the values stored will no longer exist. For more detailed information, please refer to this link. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: thank you final query only is this the only way to store data in cookie or we can store in cookie while retrieve the data from database also, when we sign using username and password  once we click the checbox the username is stored cookie and i gave logout the username is stored in the username  field,automatically it stored in username field or we want to pass the cookie value to username field.because no guide for me

Comment: I suggest you to post a new question with this.

Comment: I follow your words  is this the only way to store data in cookie or we can store the  cookie while retrieve the data from database also

Comment: Why you need this if you have already data stored in database.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply I Understood clearly thanks lot bye